# I want to read the text file up to the empty line and then delete the text that i have read from it

Tags: c#

I have this kind of text file show below. I want to read this file up to the empty line and shows  that lines in the message box and then delete the text lines including the empty line that I have just read and same process will repeats until the whole file has been read. I have just not been able to read a single line though.

```
**Hi**
**Hello**

**How are you?
I am fine.**

**And how about you?
Me too fine
Whats going on.**
```

Here is code sample.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileNameAndPath);
string line;
            try
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if(line.StartsWith(null))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(line);
                    }
                    sr.Close();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Got empty line while reading a file");
            }
```

Comment: You can't pass `null` to `StartsWith()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Try using `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StartsWith()` cant be passed `null` to.

This should work:

```
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileNameAndPath);
    string line;
                try
                {
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if(line == null || line == "")
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(line);
                        }
                        sr.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Got empty line while reading a file");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

So a couple things:
There is a difference between a null string and an empty string. You can think of a string like a cookie jar (where characters are the cookies)... An empty string (e.g. `string.empty` or `""`) is a cookie jar that has no cookies in it. Whereas `null` means there is no cookie jar at all. When you read a file line, it always returns a string, as long as there is a line to read. So an empty line comes back as an empty string.

With that being said, while it is true that an empty line starts with nothing, it is not checking the exact thing you want to know. Coding solutions that do 
almost the same thing" will get you in a lot of trouble later in life. A more appropriate check would be something like `string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)`

Finally, if you want to "delete part of the file", I would recommend actually you "remove all of the file, and then only write the part you want to remain". So what you should do is read the entire file into a `List<string>`. Then, remove the items in the List you don't want. After that, overwrite the file with the remaining items in the List. You can read and write to a file at the same time, but I personally find it messy, and I think it couples your logic. But the biggest point (in both cases) to help you look up how to do it is: Deleting info from a file is considered writing to the file. So look up how to write to a file to delete stuff from it.

Answer (score -1):

You can't pass `null` to `StartsWith()`. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx

Suggest that what you're after is

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
{
   ...
}
```